# No access to the entire drive on which Ubuntu was installed

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-8

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 for the first time on my laptop that was shipped with Windows 8.

Since my laptop has a dual storage, it has the following drives:

- C: 128G SSD
- D: 750G HDD.

I installed Ubuntu on the D: drive such that it occupies only 200G of my D: drive so that I could use the rest of the storage for my Windows.

Well that was my goal.. but it seems that Windows 8 can't detect the entire D: drive after I installed Ubuntu. It is not mounted at all. And even Ubuntu detects only the installed partition of the D: drive, which means the rest 550G was invisible somehow.

I have installed pysdm to fix mounting the drives, but it does not do any good since it doesn't show the rest of the drive at all.

Where can I find the rest of the drive visible in both Windows 8 and Ubuntu?

Comment: What is your D: drive formatted as?

Comment: Like others said check your partition type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is the case for multiple HDDs, but if you partition one HDD, windows is only capable of recognizing each adjacent partition up until it finds one it doesn't recognize, and none after. Since Windows does not recognize Linux partitions, if it comes directly after windows and you have another recognizable partition, say a different version of windows, after it, it will not recognize either of them. This is possibly your problem. If you have Ubuntu at the start of your second HDD, Windows will likely stop looking as soon as Ubuntu is detected.

I can't guarantee results, but if you put the Ubuntu partition at the very end of the second HDD, you will hopefully be able to read the rest of it. Make sure that you make Ubuntu big enough for Ubuntu data to build up, as it is much more time consuming to add space to the start of a partition than it is to add to the end. That being said, Ubuntu is capable of reading and writing to any partition without ill-effect (except the occasional trash can folder and obviously files incompatible formats; no different than if you were to use a flash drive between the two), as long as you gain r/w permission for them. This means that you will only really need room for system files, you could very-well keep all of your personal files on your windows partition if you wanted to. (When I still used windows I gave it 100 GBs, followed by a large ntfs partition for shared data and the last 50 GBs to Ubuntu, and put all personal files on the shared partition so that they were accessible to both OSes).

Also make sure that the extra partition is in a format that windows is compatible with. I used to use ntfs because I also had Snow Leapard for a while and it is compatable with all 3 OSes, FAT would also work with all 3 (this is what flash drives use by default).

Answer (score 0):

Check with partition editor or disk utility whether the 550GB is formatted as a partition or is unallocated. If it's unallocated, you'll need to create a partition in there and format it as NTFS for it to be visible to windows.